# lookup formula to find a value in another table

Tags: excel

Given the following two tables (both ListObjects), I want a formula to find the matching Wb Key in table Workbooks and populate its WbFileName. So the key "CAGR" should return "CAGR.xlsm".

I am using Excel 2016. How would you do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a simple Vlookup or index/match. What formulas have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making sure your lookup table is sorted on Key and then use:

```
=VLOOKUP([Wb Key],Table2,2,FALSE)
```